# Reusable Sessions ID

Tags: c#, asp.net

the problem I encounter is the sessions ID is reusable Even I have validation. I tried so many ways But still reusable

THIS ARE THE SAMPLE OF LINK ALREADY USED

`ChangePasswordFirst.aspx?StringQuery=JyUsduoR56hJrDdN4MtMpw==NkeG8Gt80/S8EaCXoZW41Q==`

After I click the change password 
the result URL

`ChangePasswordFirst.aspx?StringQuery=JyUsduoR56hJrDdN4MtMpw%3d%3dBYLgvxwVaGNGIvQXgGsfnw%3d%3d`

Please help thank you

Comment: You have enable the `Cookieless` on session - this must be follow you on all pages to work - either disable it on web.config, either find the real problem on your pages.

Comment: What is the question and which stack are you using?  WebForms? VMC? Cookieless sessions are deprecated since ASP.NET MVC 3 at least. You had to do something to *enable* them. They are deprecated because no matter what you do, that URL is *always* reusable. *Don't* use cookieless sessions if you don't want the URL to be reusable

Comment: I already review the code sir then I try to input some validation and add another table in SQL to save the sessions ID then validate again for one-time use only. then I test it but still reusable I don't know what to do.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Sir im using web application (Bussiness Logic and Datalayer) c# asp.net

Comment: That doesn't explain anything. Is it a WebForms application or ASP.NET MVC? Cookieless sessions are *disabled by default*. You had to *enable* them by adding `<sessionState cookieless="true" />` in web.config. Just remove that line

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos hi sir im using webforms application Sorry sir i already remove the sessionstate But still not working

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The `StringQuery=JyUsduoR56hJrDdN4MtMpw%3d%3dBYLgvxwVaGNGIvQXgGsfnw%3d%3d` Is combination of the Datetoday and IDnumber

Answer (score 0):

**Firstly,** we shouldn't pass the value of session in any url querystring. The cookies are right choice for managing any state management at client side.

The handshake between the client browser and server side are preserved as cookies in encrypted form.

**Secondly,** in case if you have to pass any cookies values, i preferred to pass in the Request header.

Please revert if it helps you.

Comment: Hi, sir Sakeri Thank you for answering my question. I already validate the querystring once he clicks again he going to redirect in UnauthorizeGuest.aspx But the when I use this (ChangePasswordFirst.aspx?StringQuery=JyUsduoR56hJrDdN4MtMpw%3d%3dBYLgvxwVaGNGIvQXgGsfnw%3d%3d) he can reuse it many times.